# Execute code before @Before method for JUnit test

Tags: junit, aspectj, java-bytecode-asm, javassist, javaagents

I need to execute some code before the @Before method of each unit test is executed. The problem is that I also need to know which test (the name is sufficient) will be executed afterwards.

I can either use AspectJ or Java Agents with bytecode manipulation to achieve this. Also the solution should work for tests where there is no @Before annotation present.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I can't modify the unit tests themselves, as I'm developing a framework for executing tests of other projects

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the TestName rule in JUnit:
http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestName.html

About the ordering, a solution could be to define a super class for your tests and put a @Before in there, as @Before methods in super classes are run before those in sub classes.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can't modify the unit tests themselves. Will edit the question

Comment: Maybe you can implement your own JUnit Runner: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/Runner.html I'm not sure how viable this option is though, as tests might want to use MockitoJUnitRunner, for instance.

Comment: Thought about this too, but then I would need to dynamically replace the normal one with instrumentation or AspectJ, and I haven't looked into this. I'm not allowed to make any static changes to the projects, so I can't use my own modified JUnit version

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a Java agent and you are not bound to Javassist or AspectJ, have a look at [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy) for doing so. You can add the code in the `MyAdvice` class to any method annotated with `@Test` given that the type name ends with `Test` (as an example) by:

```
public class MyAgent {
  public static void premain(String arg, Instrumentation inst) {
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
    .type(nameEndsWith("Test"))
    .transform((type, cl, builder) -> builder.visit(Advice
        .to(MyAdvice.class)
        .on(isAnnotatedWith(Test.class)))
    .installOn(instrumentation);
  }
}

class MyAdvice {
  @Advice.OnMethodEnter
  static void enter() {
    System.out.println("foo");
  }
}
```

Just bundle the above code to a Javaagent with the proper manifest code and register it before running. If you are running on a JDK, you can also attach the agent programmatically using the `byte-buddy-agent` project.